# CSS Animation loop

Tags: animation, css

I want to loop [animation](http://dabblet.com/gist/3509071), but i have [timing porblems](http://dabblet.com/gist/3510099). Is it possible to loop animation correct?

Comment: Please include the code in the question and choose a more descriptive title. That makes it easier for googlers to find your question & answer.

Comment: Please describe your correct timing behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.red{animation:red 2s 0s infinite alternate}
.orange{animation:orange 2s 1s infinite alternate}
.green{animation:green 2s 2s infinite alternate}
```

Comment: Yeah, [that's](http://dabblet.com/gist/3510440) right.
Also [this](http://dabblet.com/gist/3510239) version is correct too.